# Convexity conditions on domain of PDE solutions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have a little question concerning the solutions of some basic PDEs that can be found in introductory texts on the subject (the 1D wave equation for example).

Often, in the solution of such equations, there is a PDE of the form:

$$\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x} = 0$$

with $f(x,y)$ a real-valued function of 2 variables defined on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. They solve it simply by saying that "we integrate both side, and find that $f(x,y) = g(y)$ with $g$ a function of a single variable."
However, it is well known that if $U$ is not convex, this is not necessarily true (it is not hard to find a non convex domain U and a function $f$ defined on $U$, satisfying the PDE above, but depending on both $x$ and $y$).

So my question is, what should I understand from these texts ? That they make implicit assumptions on the domain $U$ ?

To take a concrete example, for the 1D wave equation: $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}$$

we find (using, among other things, the argument above) that the general solution is

$$f(x,t) = F(x - ct) + G(x + ct)$$

for arbitrary functions $F$ and $G$ of one variable. But again, usually, I see no condition on the domain of the solution.
So I suppose that, if the domain $U$ on which we want to solve the equation is not convex, we are not sure that the solution is of this form ?

Thank you for your help :-) !

EDIT: A different (but related) question would be: for a function $f$ defined on $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and satisfying

$$\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x} = g(x,y)$$

on $U$, under which conditions can we simply say "we integrate in x both sides of the equation and, provided we can solve the integral of the right hand side, we have the general solution up to an arbitrary function of y". (Let's say $f$ and $g$ are $C^1$ function for example). Is the condition $U$ convex necessary/sufficient ?

Answer (score 1):

The condition that $U$ is convex is sufficient but not necessary. (For example, you can take $U = \{ x > 0, y < 1/x\}$.)

One way to think about this is geometrically. When you solve equations like 
$$ v \cdot \nabla f = g $$
where $v$ is a given vector field and $g$ a source term, on a domain $U$, you can consider the set $\Gamma$ of all maximally extended integral curves of $v$. The freedom of choosing a constant of integration is really a freedom of assigning a mapping $\Gamma \to \mathbb{R}$. In the case where $v = \partial_x$ and $U$ is convex, it just happens that you can conveniently parametrize $\Gamma$ by $y$.

Comment: Ok, thank you :-) ! I must admit that I only have a very basic knowledge of differential geometry. I think however that I see the idea of what you say.

But I deduce from this that the subject of PDE is even more complexe that I thought it was. That's life, I suppose :-).